# The value of a register after an instruction's execution

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this MIPS code and I have a question about it.
[image: mips code]

I know that all registers have initial values 0 except t0=4, t6=4, t7=-1
Data memory has the value 4 at each word (32 bit)

I need to find the value of register $t4 after the execution of I5 (instruction 5)

Here's my try:

- I0: t1 = 0+4=4
- I1: t2 = 4+4=8
- I2: t1 = 4+4=8
- I3: t3 = 8+0=8
- I4: t4 = 8+4=12
- I5: t5 = 12+8=20

So the value of $t4 after I5 execution  is 12 but this is the wrong answer.
The right answer is 4. Where's my mistake?

Comment: Please post the code as a text (in a code block), don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: I5 is doing the sum of two load results (from I3 and I4).  There are no stores, so both load results must be `4`, and don't have to look at any earlier instructions.  Thus `$t5 = 4+4 = 8`.   Are you sure *every* word of memory has value `4`?  Because that doesn't match the answer.  (I'm assuming this is MIPS II or later so there isn't unpredictable behaviour from reading $t4 in the load delay slot.)

Comment: Your attempt seems to be calculating addresses for `lw` operations, forgetting that the `8+0` or `8+4` are used as memory addresses, not assigned to the destination register directly.

Comment: If I read correctly, `t4` was loaded from memory at line 4, and never written after that.  And you said all of memory contains the value `4`.  Thus, `t4` ends up containing the value 4.